# Stuck getting selenium code to click my link

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button but I am having an error when finding the element. In general I am trying to refresh a page until the link to join the waiting list goes live. When I run the script the webpage pulls up but does not refresh or click the join waitlist button when it is live.

I've tried finding element by class, link text, xpath, each time I get an error saying the element wasn't found.

code

```
while not joinList:
    try:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("disabled")
        print("Button isnt ready yet.")
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.refresh()

    except:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("signup-btn")
        print("Join")
        addToCartBtn.click()
        joinList = True
```

Where the element for the disabled join waitlist button is:
button _ngcontent-yur-c149="" disabled="" class="signup-btn ng-tns-c149-6 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(0, 59, 153);"> Waitlist is currently closed </button

and the element for the enabled waitlist is:
button _ngcontent-yur-c149="" class="signup-btn ng-tns-c149-4 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(0, 59, 153);"> Join waitlist </button

The error I get is:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\Main test folder\Test 1.py", line 20, in <module>
    addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("signup-btn")
  File "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Pycharm\MCattempt2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".signup-btn"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` will return lists of element change this to `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` which will return webelement.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. See above edits for the error I get when I use element instead of elements

Comment: maybe the page hasnt fully loaded yet

Comment: It is a pretty quick load. I changed it to 5 seconds pause with same result

Comment: Are you able to link the webpage?